# How to select into and specify the type of an empty column

Tags: sql-server

I'm importing two spreadsheets into one database, they both have the same number of fields and names.  The difference is that in column A of sheet A, there is data but in Column A of sheet B is data.

Using the command Select into , column A is classed as a nvarchar because it has characters in it.  However sheet B is empty and is being classed as float(8).

Is there a configuration setting that tells SQL Server to treat that if all rows are blank, treat as varchar and not float?

```
Select * into Table1 from OpenDataSource (.....) /* (Excel Sheet)*/
```

I can't always be sure that the sheet with data will be inserted first.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `SELECT *` you could do `SELECT CAST(ColumnA AS varchar(max))...`

Comment: Problem is I don't want to hardcode the fields but i won't always know what the fields are.